# Explanation for "bundle install --deployment"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand some of the details behind bundling for deployment that I can't wrap my head around. I've read a few posts on here such as this one:

[What does Rails 3's Bundler "bundle install --deployment" exactly do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681621/what-does-rails-3s-bundler-bundle-install-deployment-exactly-do)

and I feel I understand what it should do. On my computer, I ran `bundle install` initially and have been developing a project. However, I wanted to see if I could run it in deployment just to get a feel as to how a production server like Heroku sets up the application.

Therefore, I started by running `bundle install --deployment`, which correctly installs all my gems into the local `vendor/bundle` local directory. However, when I run `bundle show [GEM]`, I'm still seeing the path to my system gem. I feel it should be showing a path to the local folder, but it's not.

Can someone clear up on what my misconception is?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have to bundle install --deployment for heroku. Your gems go in .bundle

Comment: ah, you're right. My mistake. Heroku properly sets things up for you. Let's say for something like travisCI or just in general if I change the bundle path.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the description of the two on Bundler's site.

Running bundle install --deployment is to be run in the production environment, but will grab the gems from rubygems when run. Read more  [here](http://bundler.io/rationale.html) under the 'Deploying Your Application' heading for the purpose of the --deployment flag.

Comment: I took at look at the reading, and it was a pretty good summary of my understanding of bundler. However, this bullet point still leaves me confused: `Bundler will not use gems already installed to your system, even if they exist.` I seem to be missing where it says that it still grabs system gems, since this seems to be contradicting that.

Comment: My path within the project directory is: `/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/Users/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/Users/<username>/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

Comment: Do a "which gem" for me.

Comment: No sorry. What is that? Just type "which gem" in your terminal.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I get. Unless you're talking about "which [GEM_NAME]". In which case, if I run it on a random gem (such as rails), I'm getting `Users/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/rails`.

Comment: If 'which gem' is spitting out source then you have a big problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73874/discussion-between-impguard-and-liyicky).

Comment: Have you considered using rbenv? Once I picked it up I never had any questions about gem management again. Using shims is a perfect way to organize dependancies. It has a better design than RVM imho.